# Angular material - datepicker renders in body instead of containg div

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a problem with the Angular Material datepicker component.

I have created a custom component:

```html
<div class="custom-date-picker">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

When I add it to my modal, picker opens inside body instead of modal. So it is always on the bottom of the page, under modal overlay. Adding z-index wont work because it is attached to body, not to my containing div or even modal.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Missing theme styles were causing this problem. Angular CLI didn't manage to add them, so I had to import them manually.

In my *global.scss* I have added this:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Now everything works fine.